# Find a specific object at a specific coordinate in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, 2d-games

Im currently working on a 2d tile-based game and I've come to a point where I need to optimise my code quit a bit.
Im adding a lot of different elements in javas List such as trees, rocks and so on. The reason why the elements is not a static tile is because I want the player to be able to interact with elements. Therefor all elements has to be its own object and stored in a list.

The problem is whenever I want to interact with a specific element in the built in List in java I have to create a for-loop and go through every single element in the list to find the right element at the right coordinates. (such as collision and so on.)

The way I do it is like this:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();


public Element getElementOnPixel(int x, int y){`

        for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){

            int xx = elements.get(i).getX() * Game.TILE_SIZE;
            int yy = elements.get(i).getY() * Game.TILE_SIZE;
            int w = xx + elements.get(i).width;
            int h = yy + elements.get(i).height;

            if(x >= xx && x < w && y >= yy && y < h) {
                return elements.get(i);
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

As you can see above I have to go thought the whole list until I find the right element at the right coordinate. Heres where the problem pops up because I have ALOT of elements in my game. My question follows:

Is there any other way to find a specific element at a specific coordinate in javas built in Lists?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. The question is not "how do I optimize my data structure for a given requirement". The question should be "which data structures do exist; and which one has the most advantages given my requirements". In other words: you might want to study what Trees, Maps, Sets, can do for you. Meaning: if fast lookup is required; then a data structure (List) that requires linear lookup ... might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could make imaginary make some kind of grid of your game:

Like here with 
8 Cols, 4 rows  // 8 X-Positions, 4 Y-Positions

```
[E][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][E][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][E][ ][E][ ][ ][ ]
[E][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

And align it into one row (list) ->

```
[E][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][E][ ][ ][ ][ ][E][ ][E][ ][ ][ ][E][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

If you want to get the element on (x,y).
You then take the element:

```
(x,y) -> List.get(y-1 * "overall row-length" + x)
```

Example:

```
If you want to  get the element in position x = 5, y = 3
(5,3) -> List.get(3-1 * 8 + 5) = List.get(21)
```

Comment: The problem here is that i only add elements in the list and don't add blank space. So I will get an index out of bounds when because in the example above its actually only 5 elements in the list. Not the full grid.

Comment: @aGrusberg You could just instance the List with enough empty elements before. To modellise a two-dimensional data structure in a one dimensional one it is necessary to add space holders, if you don't want to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to store all the elements in a bi-dimensional matrix:

```
Element[][] allElements=new Element[maxHeight][maxWidth];
```

... where `maxHeight` and `maxWith` are expressed in pixels.

And the procedures to store and remove:

```
private void addElement(Element element)
{
    // Calculate the range X and Y occupied by the new element:
    int posXLeft=getXPosition(element);
    int posYTop=getYPosition(element);
    int posXRigth=posXLeft+element.width;
    int posYBottom=posYTop+element.height;

    // Iterate the range X and Y in the allElements in search for old elements:
    for (int y=posYTop;y<posYBottom;y++)
    {
        for (int y=posYTop;y<posYBottom;y++)
        {
            if (allElements[y][x]!=null)
            {
                // Collision detected: There was already an element in that pixel.
            }
        }
    }

    // No collision detected:
    allElements[getXPosition(element)][getYPosition(element)]=element;
}

private void removeElement(Element element)
{
    // This is a safe operation: There is no need to search for collisions.
    int posXLeft=getXPosition(element);
    int posYTop=getYPosition(element);
    allElements[posYTop][posXLeft]=null;
}


private int getXPosition(Element element)
{
    return element.getX() * Game.TILE_SIZE;
}

private int getYPosition(Element element)
{
    return element.getY() * Game.TILE_SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your X/Y coordinates to a hash key and store the elements in a Map instead of a List. When you do your lookup, you do the same conversion to find your element. For example,

```
private static String findHashKey(int x, int y) {
  return "" + x + "_" + y;
}

Map<String, Element> elements = new HashMap<>();

public Element getElementOnPixel(int x, int y) {
  return elements.get(findHashKey(x, y));
}
```

Comment: could u please give a small example of that?

Comment: Added an example to the answer.